# How to get name of color using Color Chooser in java

Tags: java

I want name of the color which is selected from Color chooser but now it is returning me the R,G,B Values. I want  the name of the color for further use.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Just wondering.. why do you need the name of the color? Can't think of a use for it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method getColor() in  http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html

This returns a Color. A number of Colors have names (http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) but most do not. As far as I know you will need to iteratre through the special names of colors to test whether the returned colour is one of those.

**EDIT** ColorChooser returns a java.awt.Color, not an RGB value. I do not know what the equals() contract for color is, but I suspect you could write:

```
Color c = chooser.getColor();
if (Color.BLACK.equals(c)) {
    // the color is black...
}
```

The named colors are:

```
    static Color    black
          The color black.
static Color    BLACK
          The color black.
static Color    blue
          The color blue.
static Color    BLUE
          The color blue.
static Color    cyan
          The color cyan.
static Color    CYAN
          The color cyan.
static Color    DARK_GRAY
          The color dark gray.
static Color    darkGray
          The color dark gray.
static Color    gray
          The color gray.
static Color    GRAY
          The color gray.
static Color    green
          The color green.
static Color    GREEN
          The color green.
static Color    LIGHT_GRAY
          The color light gray.
static Color    lightGray
          The color light gray.
static Color    magenta
          The color magenta.
static Color    MAGENTA
          The color magenta.
static Color    orange
          The color orange.
static Color    ORANGE
          The color orange.
static Color    pink
          The color pink.
static Color    PINK
          The color pink.
static Color    red
          The color red.
static Color    RED
          The color red.
static Color    white
          The color white.
static Color    WHITE
          The color white.
static Color    yellow
          The color yellow.
static Color    YELLOW
          The color yellow.
```

Comment: getColor() returns RGB value 
For example.If i choose "white" it gives me 
==>java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly more extensive list of colours you could consider parsing something like the [X11 rgb.txt](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/research/projects/poplog/freebsd/new/rgb.txt) file and matching to entries within that.

Answer (score 0):

You may find some domain-specific naming schemes like [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) or [HTML4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_color_names) but I don't think you'll find **one** standard. For example, Wikipedia's [color list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors) is based on the previous mentioned scheme, Xona.com [color list](http://xona.com/colorlist/) is slightly different, etc.

I'm not sure Java has chosen one standard (over another) and offers color names for RGB colors. So I guess you'll have to pick one and to implement a custom conversion class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This service maps many, many color names:

http://chir.ag/projects/name-that-color/

I don't know whether it can/should be used as a webservice though.