# Java - toString to Colour

Tags: java, colors, rgb, tostring

I have been trying to work this out all day.

Basically I have made a for loop which adds entries into an arraylist. One of the entries is a "Colour" varible. I have used the `random.nextInt` to create new values for the red, green and blue parts of the colour constructor. I have also set a `toString` method so I can see the values going into the arraylist.

Problem is:

When printing out I get  :  `java.awt.Color[r=248,g=103,b=53]`

and I understand why that is so, I'm just wondering how I can change that so the output says the word "orange" or "green" or "purple" depending on what the random rgb values are.

I looked on here and I found that I could possibly use the `getRGB` method and parsing and thats where I get stuck... any help would be great :)

Comment: where have you set this toString method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get name of color using Color Chooser in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654582/how-to-get-name-of-color-using-color-chooser-in-java)

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126029/java-color-code-convert-to-color-name

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which extends Color and has a String named "colorName", then print it on toString.

By default, Color do not store this name, also, it's hard do identify colors by comparing these Red, Green, Blue values.

Answer (score 1):

This does not exist.  Good luck with rolling your own - it would need to return one of 256 x 256 x 256 (16,777,216) distinct strings to work.  How would you distinguish all the shades of blue, for example?  Why doesn't the RGB value work for you?

Comment: I can get the RGB values to work but I wanted to see if it was possible to get the name to display. What I need to do is generate a random colour for each "election party" and then in the arraylist add votes. I might just make an array of colours (words) and not let the number of election parties be no more then the size of the color arraylist...probably easier :P

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass Color and override the toString method (or create a printColour method or whatever name) and then you could output a certain colour label for a certain range of RGB values.

Obviously your choice of the colour names and the specific range you assign them will be completely subjective.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `Color` to either override the `toString()` method or add another method of your own to covert the RGB to a named color. Or you could have a static method somewhere that converts RGB to a named color.

However given there are 256 * 256 * 256 =~ 16 million different RGB combinations most of your random RGB combinations will not correspond to a named color. So not sure it's worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is non-trivial and rather subjective.

However, you might want to look at http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/ which attempts to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

I've never really came across something you're asking for, but would this work for you? (You might need to [add more colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors) for your needs) :

```
public final class ColorUtil {

    static private HashMap<String,Color> KNOWNCOLORS = new HashMap<String,Color>();

    static {
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("black",     Color.black);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("darkgray",  Color.darkGray);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("lightgray", Color.lightGray);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("white",     Color.white);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("red",       Color.red);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("blue",      Color.blue);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("green",     Color.green);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("pink",      Color.pink);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("cyan",      Color.cyan);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("purple",    Color.magenta);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("orange",    Color.orange);
        KNOWNCOLORS.put("yellow",    Color.yellow);
        // add more here
    }


    static public String getBestColorName(Color c) {
        int dist, diff = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        String colorName = toHex(c);
        Color c2;

        for (String name : KNOWNCOLORS.keySet()) {
            c2 = KNOWNCOLORS.get(name);
            dist = Math.abs(c.getRed() - c2.getRed())
                    + Math.abs(c.getGreen() - c2.getGreen()) 
                    + Math.abs(c.getBlue() - c2.getBlue())
                    + Math.abs(c.getAlpha() - c2.getAlpha());

            if (dist < diff) {
                diff = dist;
                colorName = name; 
            }
        }

        return colorName;
    }

    static public int getColorValue(Color c) {
        return (c.getAlpha() << 24) 
            | (c.getRed() << 16)
            | (c.getGreen() << 8) 
            | (c.getBlue()); 
    }

    static public String toHex(Color c) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        if (c.getAlpha() < 255) {
            b.append(padLeft(Integer.toString(c.getAlpha(), 16), 2));
        }
        b.append(padLeft(Integer.toString(c.getRed(), 16), 2));
        b.append(padLeft(Integer.toString(c.getGreen(), 16), 2));
        b.append(padLeft(Integer.toString(c.getBlue(), 16), 2));

        return b.toString();
    }

    static private String padLeft(String s, int n) {
        return String.format("%1$#" + n + "s", s).replace(" ", "0");
    }

    private ColorUtil() {}



    static public void main(String...args) {
        Color c;

        for (String name : KNOWNCOLORS.keySet()) {
            if (!name.equals(getBestColorName(KNOWNCOLORS.get(name)))) {
                System.out.println("*** ERR!! Could not match color " + name);
            } 
        }

        for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
            c = new Color((int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256), (int) (Math.random() * 256));

            System.out.println("Color " + toHex(c) 
                 + " (" + c.getAlpha() + "," + c.getRed() + "," + c.getGreen() + "," + c.getBlue() + ")"
                 + " = " + getBestColorName(c));
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

}
```

Sample output :

```
Color e75848 (255,231,88,72) = red
Color 6f4854 (255,111,72,84) = darkgray
Color 5dc6af (255,93,198,175) = lightgray
Color 190971 (255,25,9,113) = darkgray
Color 8ef300 (255,142,243,0) = yellow
Color c2ec5b (255,194,236,91) = lightgray
Color 998794 (255,153,135,148) = lightgray
Color 328d06 (255,50,141,6) = darkgray
Color 223d03 (255,34,61,3) = darkgray
Color 51dfea (255,81,223,234) = cyan
Color baa801 (255,186,168,1) = orange
Color 8370d4 (255,131,112,212) = lightgray
Color 7766bd (255,119,102,189) = lightgray
Color 35024b (255,53,2,75) = darkgray
Color cdbfad (255,205,191,173) = lightgray
Color 5e3a21 (255,94,58,33) = darkgray
Color 11af5d (255,17,175,93) = darkgray
Color 480995 (255,72,9,149) = darkgray
Color 04adab (255,4,173,171) = cyan
Color 98641c (255,152,100,28) = darkgray
Color 3ef68c (255,62,246,140) = cyan
Color 4d091a (255,77,9,26) = darkgray
Color 56117d (255,86,17,125) = darkgray
Color 1a00ea (255,26,0,234) = blue
Color 2ffd3e (255,47,253,62) = green
Color 9a918b (255,154,145,139) = lightgray
Color 6f8f0e (255,111,143,14) = darkgray
Color 5f3e25 (255,95,62,37) = darkgray
Color 914e79 (255,145,78,121) = darkgray
Color 57f88b (255,87,248,139) = cyan
Done!
```